# Unsupported Media Type - Spring Boot Rest Controller has consumes/produces JSON and XML but only accepts Json

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot, rest

I have a requirement that needs to the controller be able to receive both JSON and XML.

I have put the `produces` and `consumes` tags in the RequestMapping but it is not working. When i do a POST to the endpoint using JSON as the body, it work fine.

When i do a POST using a XML as the body the HTTP message `415 Unsupported Media Type` is thrown.

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendarios-publicacao",
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
public class CalendarioPublicacaoController implements ControllerFacade<CalendarioPublicacaoDto, CalendarioPublicacaoDto> {

    @Autowired
    private CalendarioPublicacaoService calendarioPublicacaoService;


    @Override
    @PostMapping
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Calendário de publicação criado com sucesso."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Dados enviados incorretamente."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Sem permissões para criar calendários de publicação."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Já existe um calendário para este módulo.")
    })
    public ResponseEntity<CalendarioPublicacaoDto> create(@RequestBody  CalendarioPublicacaoDto object, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create(request.getRequestURL().append("/").append(calendarioPublicacaoService.create(object).getId()).toString())).build();
    }

}
```

Example of the request with curl:

I receive 415.

```
curl -v -XPOST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CalendarioPublicacaoDto>
<anoReferencia>0</anoReferencia>
<dataSensibilizacao>2022-02-09T18:56:36.525Z</dataSensibilizacao>
<entidade>SESI</entidade>
<modulo>
<id>4</id>
</modulo>
<periodicidade>AUTOMATICO</periodicidade>
<periodoReferencia>0</periodoReferencia>
</CalendarioPublicacaoDto>' 'localhost:9090/calendarios-publicacao'
```

And via Insomnia the same 415 error.

Should I create an configuration class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I only needed to add the @XmlRootElement(name="") annotation in my Dto.